# R to pdf, code and plots off the edge of the page

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown

I've tried looking online, but I can't seem to find any working answers.

I have a rmd notebook that is full of plots. Everything works correctly when it is run, and saved. When I knit it to html, everything renders correctly.

However, when I knit it to pdf, a number of things happen:

1. The code does not wrap inside the code box, but runs off the right hand side of the page.
2. The outputs from the code run off the outputs of the page, instead of wrapping.
3. The first plot is fine, but all subsequent plots are offset incrementaly to the right (so plot 2 is slightly further right, plot 3 is right of center, and so on).
4. The headers that should be above the code boxes are below the plot, even though they are not in the code box.

I am assuming that all of these issues are related, however, I can't seem to find a way of resolving them. The blocks of code I have at the start of the rmd are:

````
---
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

...

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
````

Any suggestions on how to fix would be gratefully approeciated.

Edit:

original code:

## Various Violin plots

##### size in bytes vs  price

```
p <- ggplot(apple_df, 
            aes(price, size_bytes), 
            )

p + geom_violin() + coord_flip() + labs(
    x = "Price in USD",
    y = "Size in bytes", 
    title = "Violin plot - size in bytes vs price"
)
```

Output in pdf:

[image]
[image]

Original code:

```
corr_1 <- cor(apple_df$size_bytes, apple_df$user_rating)
if (corr_1 < -0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a strong negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a weak negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 >= -0.1 && corr_1 <= 0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is no correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong positive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ". This suggests there is a strong postive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a weak postive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak positive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
}
```

Output in PDF:
[image]

2nd edit:

Sample code chunk.

## Q4: Find the sum of app sizes in each genre, using groupby.

*Adapted from: [https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/r-group-by-function-from-dplyr/#:~:text=Dplyr%20group_by%20Function%20Example,frame%20as%20a%20first%20argument](https://sparkbyexamples.com/r-programming/r-group-by-function-from-dplyr/#:%7E:text=Dplyr%20group_by%20Function%20Example,frame%20as%20a%20first%20argument)*

```
group_by_table <- apple_df %>% group_by(apple_df$prime_genre)
agg_table <- group_by_table %>% summarise(sum(size_bytes))
agg_df <- agg_table %>% as.data.frame()
colnames(agg_df) <- c("App genres", "Sum of app sizes (in bytes)")
agg_df
```

## Q5, i: Are larger apps (larger size in bytes) higher-rated by customers - using correlation?

```
corr_1 <- cor(apple_df$size_bytes, apple_df$user_rating)
if (corr_1 < -0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a strong negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a weak negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 < -0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak negative correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 >= -0.1 && corr_1 <= 0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is no correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong positive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ". This suggests there is a strong postive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else if (corr_1 > 0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a weak postive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
} else {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_1, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak positive correlation between app size and customer rating"))
}
```

## Q5, ii: Are apps with more ratings higher-rated - using correlation?

```
corr_2 <- cor(apple_df$rating_count_tot, apple_df$user_rating)
if (corr_2 < -0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong negative correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 < -0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a strong negative correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 < -0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a weak negative correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 < -0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak negative correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 >= -0.1 && corr_2 <= 0.1) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is no correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 > 0.75) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very strong positive correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 > 0.5) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a strong postive correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else if (corr_2 > 0.25) {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ". This suggests there is a weak postive correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
} else {
  cat(paste("The correlation between app size and ratings is", round(corr_2, digits = 2), ".\nThis suggests there is a very weak positive correlation between the number of ratings submitted and customer rating."))
}
```

Versions:
RStudio: 202.09.1 build 494
R: 4.3.2
dplyr: 1.1.3
ggplot2: 3.4.4

Comment: It would help a lot if you could make a minimal reproducible example. Can you make a sample file with 2 plots and 1 or 2 code blocks that illustrates the problem?

Comment: It may also help to have some system info - what versions of rmarkdown and pandoc are you running, and what's your OS?

Comment: @GregorThomas added in screenshots, and origianl code blocks as examples.

Comment: I think the line breaks may be as expected. Where HTML is expected to resize/wrap text based on the window width, PDF is fixed. I am not surprised that the PDF does not create linebreaks in your code when none are there.

Comment: As for your plot, the `ggplot` code isn't really part of the problem, what we mostly need to see is any chunk options you've set. And the versions I ask for in my comment above might be nice.